# how to create Lua methods that work with tables automatically

Tags: class, methods, lua, lua-table

In Lua, I see some methods such as the `string` and `io` class that allows you to call the method from the table automatically, without the need to instantiate an object for this, example:

the following code:

```lua
local tb = {"Hello", "World!"}

table.concat(tb)
```

can be written like this:

```lua
local tb = {"Hello", "World!"}

tb:concat()
```

I tried to create a method that could do the same thing:

```lua
local tst = {}

function tst:test()
     print("test")
end
```

but the following code does not work:

```lua
local tb = {"Hello", "World!"}

tb:test()
```

only if I inform the code that `tb = tst`:

```lua
local tb = tst

tb:test()
```

my question is, **there any way for me to create methods that work with a string, or a table automatically as in the second example without the need to instantiate the class? like, calling my table as a table:MyMethod()**

Comment: `tb:concat()` does not work out of the box. You need to give `tb` a metatable.

Comment: @lhf How should i create this metatable? like, what kind of metamethods should i use to make this possible?

Comment: `__index`, Lua has a great manual i suggest you give it a read. [Programming in Lua: 13.4.1 – The __index Metamethod](https://www.lua.org/pil/13.4.1.html) also related [16.1 Classes](https://www.lua.org/pil/16.1.html)

Comment: @Nifim thanks for the links, but i took a good look at them and didn't find what i need. I have an average knowledge of metamethods, I work with them by OOP, but in OOP you need to instantiate an object before working with the methods, and I need to know how to use these methods of a class without instantiating, like the standard Lua methods like `string`, `io`, `table`, etc ...

Comment: What lua environment are you working in? have you tried just adding the methods to `table`?

Comment: @Nifim I am working with Lua in version 5.4, in IDE SciTE. My idea is to create methods like the standard Lua methods so that they can then be imported and used normally, but I would like that the methods could be used directly without the need to instantiate the table of those methods, that is, use them directly, for example, instead of using `table.concat(MyTable)`, use `MyTable:concat()` without the need to do `MyTable = table`, and only for my own methods

Comment: You always have to instantiate an object in order to call methods on it. Strings are instantiated with string literals. Files are instantiated with `io.open`. Tables are instantiated with `{}`, plus you have to give them a metatable to provide the methods.

Comment: @luther thank you for the information <3. Would you like to tell me how I would make the metatable to detect these elements? for example, how `table` detects that `{}` is instantiating him

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this answers your original question, but maybe answering your question from the comments will help explain things.

The following code is an example of how you might instantiate a table with some methods.

```
local function makeArray()
  local a = {}
  setmetatable(a, {__index = table})
  return a
end
```

The `setmetatable` call basically makes all the functions from the `table` library accessible from the new array. This is useful, because all the `table` functions except `pack` expect an array as their first argument.

Vanilla Lua does something similar for strings. All strings have `{__index = string}` as their metatable.

Comment: wonderful, thanks for the answer <3. taking the opportunity to ask, do you know how the `table` class detects that `local set = {}` is an instance of it? that is, how does table understand that `{}` instantiates `table`, or `" "` instantiates `string` when we declare the variable

Comment: `table` is not a class, and it doesn't know anything about other tables. The key is that an object needs to know where to find its methods. In the above code, `setmetatable` stores a reference to `table` on `a` itself. If you do something like `a:concat()`, `a` can use that reference to `table` to find the `concat` function. Note that with `local set = {}`, there is no metatable, and `set` has no methods. As for strings, they're different from tables in that they have only one metatable that applies to the whole data type.

Answer (score 1):

luther is spot on although the code can be shortened:

```
function makeArray()
  return setmetatable({}, {__index = table})
end
```